# If Matrix $A^2=A$, does that mean $Ax=0$ has a unique solution for $A_{ n \times n}, x_{n \times 1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If Matrix $A^2=A$ and $A$ is not $0$, does that mean $Ax=0$ has a unique solution for $A_{n\times n}, x_{n\times 1}$?

How can I prove it?

Comment: No, it is not true, even if you assume $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A^2=A$ then $A(I-A)=0$ so $x=(I-A)v$ for any $v$ has $Ax=0$. Also, if $Ax=0$ then $x=(I-A)x$. So the set of solutions to $Ax=0$ is the range of $I-A$.

So the dimension of the space of solutions is determined by the rank of $A-I$.

If you take $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$ you can get $$(I-A)\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No -- consider for example $A=({}^1_0\,{}^0_0)$.

Comment: ... id est, if and only if $A=I$ :)

Comment: Hmm, yes, bad point. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

$A \vec x = \vec 0$ has a unique solution if and only if $A$ is invertible (why?), if and only if $A$ is non-singular.

Consider the equation $A^2=A$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
A^2 &=& A \\
\det{A^2} &=& \det A \\
(\det A)^2 &=& \det A
\end{array}$$

We can have $\det A$ be $0$ or $1$, so $A$ can be singular (can we construct such a matrix?).

If $A$ is singular, then $A \vec x = \vec 0$ does not have a unique solution.

Comment: Since we haven't learned determinant yet, is there any other way to word it?